# How to tell how long it took for a RDP Session to establish a connection?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, logging, rdp, windows-event-log

Are there logs, or fields inside of logs that tell when the connection was initiated and established? Inside of Event ID 4624 there is a `TimeCreated [SystemTime]` field, but I am hoping to audit how long it takes to connect not just the time the connection was established.

I am running Windows Server 2012R2 and a few to be discontinued 2008R2, and am running majority Windows 8 and Windows 10 thin clients.

Comment: Do you want to know how long it takes from the time a user clicks the Connect button in the RDP client until the time their remote session desktop loads? If so, make a connection and time it.

Comment: The short answer is no, which is why @joequerty offered the suggestion he did. You should also be aware a number of factors can affect the result. These include if NLA is enabled on the RDS server. While I understand the desire to have an average connection time to troubleshoot issues or answer questions from executives what you are asking for is not available from event logs.

Comment: My comment isn't an answer, hence why it's a comment. There aren't any logs that can tell you the time it took from session initiation to session establishment. If you want to get an idea of how long it takes then establish a session and time it. Establish 10 sessions and then average them. Establish 100 sessions and then average them. However many you think is appropriate to establish a "baseline". Also, if you don't like a comment then simply state that, don't be a jerk about it. Being an ass will get you the same in return.

Comment: Welcome to the community, Bridger! ;) If I were you, i'd perform a test connection and then analyze the logs generated by that session on the RDP server. It sounds like you've identified the security logon event, but there are also logs generated in the Terminal Services event logs and also Application/System that might indicate when the complete session is finished setting up.

Comment: user5870571 @twconnell You have answered my question. Thanks.